# Convert JSON value field with aeson

Tags: haskell, hashmap, aeson

Scenario: I need to read in a JSON file and then update the value field within abcs to an absolute path.

The keys related to the value fields are not static, and therefore I would like to perform it using the hashmaps.

My challenge is, that I keep going round and round in the types and cannot figure out how to convert them. Ideally, updatePaths should return IO Object.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "abcs": {
        "{crtl}": "crtl.abc",
        "{wt}": "wt.abc"
    }
}
```

**Haskell:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module TCT.ScenarioRunner where
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as Hm
import Data.Text.Internal
import Filesystem.Path
import System.Path.NameManip (absolute_path)

loadFile :: IO B.ByteString
loadFile = B.readFile "resources/initialise_body.json"

initialise :: String -> IO ()
initialise sessionId = do
  raw <- loadFile
  let json = (eitherDecode raw) :: Either String Value
  case json of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right (Object ps) -> 
          case Hm.lookup "abcs" ps of
            Nothing -> putStrLn "Could not find abcs"
            Just (Object abcs) -> do
              (putStrLn "Found abcs")
              result <- print $ updatePaths abcs
              putStrLn "Bla"
  putStrLn "TBD: initialise"

updatePaths :: Object -> Object
updatePaths obj = Hm.map createFullPath obj
  where createFullPath val = absolute_path ("resources/abcs/" ++ val)
```

**Error:**

```
src/TCT/ScenarioRunner.hs:71:22-46: error: …
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘Value’
      Expected type: Object
        Actual type: Hm.HashMap Text (IO String)
    • In the expression: Hm.map createFullPath obj
      In an equation for ‘updatePaths’:
          updatePaths obj
            = Hm.map createFullPath obj
            where
                createFullPath val = absolute_path ("resources/abcs/" ++ val)
   |
src/TCT/ScenarioRunner.hs:71:44-46: error: …
    • Couldn't match type ‘Value’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: Hm.HashMap Text [Char]
        Actual type: Object
    • In the second argument of ‘Hm.map’, namely ‘obj’
      In the expression: Hm.map createFullPath obj
      In an equation for ‘updatePaths’:
          updatePaths obj
            = Hm.map createFullPath obj
            where
                createFullPath val = absolute_path ("resources/abcs/" ++ val)
   |
Compilation failed.
```

**Update:** 
Probies solution is almost correct, I made a few changes, so the solution becomes:

```
 updatePaths :: Object -> IO Object
 updatePaths (obj :: Object) = traverse createFullPath obj
  where
    createFullPath :: Value -> IO Value
    createFullPath (String val) =
      (String . T.pack) <$> absolute_path ("resources/abcs/" ++ (T.unpack val))
    createFullPath x = pure x -- Ignore non strings
```

**Update 2:**
In order to understand the solution better I looked at the traverse type signature. 
Traverse has the type signature: `... =>  (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`

`a` must be `Value`;

`f` must be `IO`;

`t` must be `HashMap Text`, as `Object` is a type synonym for `HashMap Text Value`

This gives us: `(Value -> IO Value) -> HashMap Text Value -> IO (HashMap Text Value)` or IO Object as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. Firstly, you have a HashMap of Aeson `Value`, not `String` so we need to pattern match to get out our "String". Secondly the "String type" Aeson uses is `Text`, whilst `absolute_path` wants a regular string, so we'll need to do some conversion. Third, `absolute_path` will return an `IO` value, so we'll need to use `traverse` instead of a `map`.

So, assuming you've already imported `Data.Text` as `T`

```
updatePaths :: Object -> IO Object
updatePaths obj = traverse createFullPath obj
  where 
    createFullPath (String val) = 
      (String . T.pack) <$> absolute_path ("resources/abcs/" ++ (T.unpack val))
    createFullPath x = pure x -- Ignore non strings
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to make two slight changes, I have written it in the original post. I might follow up with a few questions later on, when I have time :)

Comment: Also seems like, if Object <$> is removed, then it returns IO Object. Object is a function from Object to Value

Comment: I've fixed it here as well